# File path issues with move_uploaded_file

Tags: php, html

I am trying to upload pictures on my site. However, I am trying to find the correct filepath to the folder I need to send the pictures too. I continue to get a 500 server internal error when move_uploaded_file() is called. I tried playing around with a couple of things, and I believe the problem is that I am not using the correct destination folder.

```
    <?php

    $target_path = "G:\\PleskVhosts\\missed-moments.com\\httpdocs\\uploads\\";

    $target_path = $target_path . basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']); 

    echo $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] . "<br/>";
    echo $target_path;  
    echo getcwd()."<br/>";


    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadedfile']['tmp_name'], $target_path)) {
        echo "The file ".  basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name'])." has been uploaded";
    } else{
        echo "There was an error uploading the file, please try again!";
    }

    ?>
```

I tried to find the path of the folder I was in by using :

```
echo $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] . "<br/>";
echo getcwd()."<br/>";
```

And then I tried to hardcode the same address with the addition of the folder that I want to save the pictures in it. I was hoping somebody could give me some other suggestions on how to resolve this issue.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Did the make sure the user that the PHP server is running as has permissions to write into that folder?

Comment: I did not check that...I will do that now. Will move_uploaded_file create that file if it does not exist? That thought just popped into my mind.

Comment: Check your server error log for more information on the error. Also, what size file are you trying to upload?

Comment: The file size is about 200 kb.

Comment: Is this for use on your own machine or is it being used on a hosted service?

Comment: If the *folder* does not exist, `move_uploaded_file` will not create it.  However, if the *file* does not exist, then it will certainly be created as the target of the move.

Comment: It is being used on a hosted service. The folder does exist, I just do not think I am getting the path correct. However, I just try to upload the file to the current path and that gave the 500 internal server error as well.

Comment: Then don't do `$target_path = "G:\\PleskVhosts\\missed-moments.com\\httpdocs\\uploads\\";` do `$target_path = "uploads/";` if running script from your root. Or `$target_path = "/var/home/user/you/uploads/";`

Comment: Same error so maybe it is a permissions issue? I am trying to find the error logs but not sure how to do that quite yet.

Comment: It could be a permissions issue. First try chmod'ing to `755` and worse case scenario, try `777`

Comment: The chmod causes a 500 internal server error as well. I tried it before and after I appended the file name. I really need to figure out this error reporting.

Comment: If you use Firezilla, you can view your files and directories on your shared server. You will be able to see and change what file and directory privileges are set. There may be an easier way, but Firezilla is very useful besides for managing files.

Comment: Hey everybody, I got it fixed. I did not have permissions to write to the file. I figured out how to manually change the permissions on godaddy because chmod does not work. Thanks for all of your help!!